# AutoMapper Custom Resolver asking for optional parameters in constructor

Tags: c#, automapper

I am having some issues with a custom resolver in AutoMapper. I am passing in a interface to the constructor of my repository but i keep getting the following error:

```
Type needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args
Parameter name: type
```

I can get around it by creating a parameter-less constructor and hard coding the concrete implementation of my repo in there, but i want to inject it.

**My Resolver:**

```
public class OptionGroupProjectionResolver : ValueResolver<Product, List<OptionGroupProjection>>
{
    private readonly IOptionGroupRepository _optionGroupRepository;

    public OptionGroupProjectionResolver(IOptionGroupRepository optionGroupRepository)
    {
        _optionGroupRepository = optionGroupRepository;
    }

    protected override List<OptionGroupProjection> ResolveCore(Product source)
    {
        var groupIds = new List<int>();
        var optIds = new List<int>();

        foreach (var variant in source.Variants)
        {
            groupIds.AddRange(variant.Options.Select(option => option.GroupId).Distinct());
            optIds.AddRange(variant.Options.Select(option => option.Id).Distinct());
        }

        var groups = _optionGroupRepository.GetAll();

        var results = from gr in groups
                      where groupIds.Contains(gr.Id)
                      select new OptionGroupProjection
                      {
                          Id = gr.Id,
                          Name = gr.Name,
                          Options = gr.Options.Where(o => optIds.Contains(o.Id)).ToList()
                      };

        return results.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Ninject Config for Repo**

```
_kernel.Bind<IOptionGroupRepository>().To<OptionGroupRepository>();
```

**Mapping Config**

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDetailsViewModel>()
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.DefaultImage,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Images.OrderBy(i => i.SortOrder).FirstOrDefault())
            )
            .ForMember(
                dest => dest.SelectOptionGroups,
                opt => opt.ResolveUsing<OptionGroupProjectionResolver>()
            );
```

I can't really see what i can do, i am sure i have set something up wrong by my Google skills are failing me today.

Comment: It looks like Automapper is trying to construct the `OptionGroupProjectionResolver` so it doesn't know about your ninject configuration.

Comment: you ever get this working?  I have almost the exact same issue right now

Comment: Not for this as i changed the implementation to not use a repo in the end.  But i have done this after (i think) using an attribute called [ImportingConstructor].  I think i got the answer from this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204664/automapper-together-with-dependency-injection

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside of your bootstrapping/initialization code, you need to tell AutoMapper how to resolve dependencies. I haven't used Ninject, but it might be something like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(t => _kernel.Get(t));
```

The lambda is what AutoMapper will execute to resolve dependencies at runtime.

Comment: Will check that out and come back