# AutoMapper: Map to a Destination Type with Constructor Injection (Prism, Unity, EntityFramework)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, prism, unity-container

I ran into a little Problem in my WPF Prism.Unity(7.2.0.1367) Application with EntityFramework(6.3.0), AutoMapper(9.0.0) and AutoMapper.EF6(2.0.0) which I can't seem to figure out on my own:

I have a `FooListViewModel` that loads a List of `FooEntity`s from EntityFramework and maps them to `FooViewModel`s using AutoMapper. The `FooEntity` has a 1-to-many Relationship to `BarEntity` which turns into an ObservableCollection of `BarViewModel`s in the `FooViewModel`. So far so good. Now I wanted to give the `FooViewModel` access to the DbContext and added the Dependency to the `FooViewModel`'s Ctor, which is when AutoMapper started to complain that "FooViewModel needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args".

This is the `FooViewModel` (All Properties are actually full Properties using INotifyPropertyChanged but I shortened it to achieve better readability):

```
public class FooViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<BarViewModel> Bars { get; set; }

    public FooViewModel(FooBarContext context) // <-- this is the problem
    {

    }
}
```

After reading this post:
[AutoMapper Custom Resolver asking for optional parameters in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525853/automapper-custom-resolver-asking-for-optional-parameters-in-constructor)

I started by adding `ConstructServicesUsing(x => IUnityContainer.Resolve(x))`:

```
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        IUnityContainer _container = containerRegistry.GetContainer();

        MapperConfiguration mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<FooProfile>();
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(x => _container.Resolve(x));
        });

        IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();

        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(mapper);
    }
```

... but the Issue persisted. Then I found this post:
[AutoMapper dependency injection with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229719/automapper-dependency-injection-with-parameters)

So I created a TypeConverter:

```
public class FooConverter : ITypeConverter<Foo, FooViewModel>
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public FooConverter(IUnityContainer container, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _container = container;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public FooViewModel Convert(Foo source, FooViewModel destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        FooViewModel result = new FooViewModel(_container.Resolve<FooBarContext>());

        result.FooId = source.FooId;
        result.Name = source.Name;
        result.Desc = source.Desc;

        result.Bars = _mapper.Map<ObservableCollection<BarViewModel>>(source.Bars);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And my Application is working again! BUT: it seems to me like I'm missing something here. Assigning all the Properties "by Hand" in my TypeConverter just to get a Dependency into the Ctor feels like missing the Point of using AutoMapper. It feels like a One-Liner like `ConstructServicesUsing(x => IUnityContainer.Resolve(x))` should tell the Mapper to get all Constructor Dependencies from the DI Container without using any TypeConverter. Plus, if I add another Dependency to my `FooViewModel` Ctor, I will have to change the TypeConverter. If I start to add Dependencies to `BarViewModel`, I will need to change the `Foo` TypeConverter AND create a `Bar` TypeConverter. It has to be simpler than that! (?)

Comment: In all honesty, I always wondered what the actual use of AutoMapper might be. Also, if you can convert from model to view model automatically, you're doing something wrong or your app is quite trivial (in which case you could just use the model as view model).

Comment: Why `ObservableCollection`? That only makes sense if the collection is either updated from the database (which EF doesn't do) or from the view model (which only makes sense if the changes are saved to the database, which AutoMapper cannot do).

Comment: Also, `new FooViewModel(_container.Resolve<FooBarContext>())` totally defeats the purpose of using a dependency injection container and is an anti-pattern (see https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

Comment: The ObservableCollection is updated from the ViewModel, because every FooView  has a Button which is bound to a DelegateCommand that can change the ViewModel's Status. And yes, I know that ```new FooViewModel(_container.Resolve<FooBarContext>())``` is bad practice, that's why I posted this question. Anyway, it's not about this App per se, which is indeed just a trivial example App I created at home. I want to know how to resolve Dependencies in AutoMapper Mappings in general, which is something I feel should be easily possible.

Comment: _In all honesty, I always wondered what the actual use of AutoMapper might be._

A good example would be an API Controller reading an Object from Database and turning it into a DTO (with less Properties than the Db Model) before returning it to the caller.

Comment: You should inject `FooBarContext` into your resolver/converter.